# C++ call public parent class method via its derived class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class that I defined like this:

```
namespace yxs
{
    class File
    {
    public:
        File(std::string fileName);
        virtual ~File();
        bool isExists();
        size_t size();

    protected:
        std::string fileName;
        std::ifstream* inputStream;
        std::ofstream* outputStream;
}
```

Then I created a child class inheriting the above base class:

```
namespace yxs
{
    class InputFile : File
    {
    public:
        InputFile(std::string fileName);
        virtual ~InputFile();
    };
}
```

From within another unrelated class, I instantiated the child class and tried to invoke the method: `isExists()`

```
void yxs::Engine::checkFile()
{
    bool isOK = this->inputFile->isExists(); // Error on compile in this line

    if(!isOK)
    {
        printf("ERROR! File canot be opened! Please check whether the file exists or not.\n");

        exit(1);
    }
}
```

However, the app won't compile. The compiler gave two error messages:

`Engine.cpp:66:34: 'isExists' is a private member of 'yxs::File'`

and:

`Engine.cpp:66:17: Cannot cast 'yxs::InputFile' to its private base class 'yxs::File'`

Those errors also happened when I tried to call `size()` method.

Why this error happened? In inheritance concept, it is allowed to call parent class method from its child isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change it from private to public inheritance:

```
class InputFile: public File
```

Without the public keyword all the members of File become private members of InputFile.